# My delegate function IS being called, still my UI does not update accordingly

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, delegates, uikit

My delegation pattern works (if my delegate function just has to print statements about the data passed back) (programmatic layout, no IB segues). But the receiver class does not update its UI accordingly. This – I believe – closes out the case, that my delegation pattern is wrong.
How is it possible that my UI is not updating? What circumstances usually prevent that? I am dealing manual entries here, *no network calls, no large amount of data or anything like that*.
For example my delegate function is :

```
class DetailTableViewController: AddVCDelegate {

//delegate function of AddVCDelgate protocol

func didAddLesson(lesson: Lesson) { // my addVC is calling this through delegate
    self.lesson = lesson
    print("delegate function set navitem title: \(lesson.name!)")//printed out correctly
    self.navigationItem.title = lesson.name! //nothing changes
          self.tableView.reloadData()// no reload
}

/*Here lesson.name got printed out nicely, navigationItem title does not change accordingly , tableView does not reload data.*/
```

Back in AddVC ViewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let vc = DetailTableViewController()
    self.delegate = vc //etc..}
```

and AddVC uses this function:

```
   func passLesson() {
    if let lesson = lesson,
        let delegate = self.delegate {
               delegate.didAddLesson(lesson: lesson)
           }
}
```

I just posted this little snippet only, because the project is a bit too complicated now to copy here, but I believe this is the relevant part of the code for the problem. I can it update with more details if needed. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I have uploaded a simple demo project to GitHub which is reproducing the problem, I hope it helps to see the real cause of the problem. I am still desperatly looking, what I am doing wrong here.

[github.com/gerkov77/DataPassing/tree/master](http://github.com/gerkov77/DataPassing/tree/master)

Comment: Show how you are setting the delegate on the object that calls `didAddLesson`. The most common error is not calling the delegate method on an on-screen instance of the view controller.

Comment: Updated the code.

Comment: @Paulw11, AddVC her is already the third on the navigation stack, since I have a mainVC presentig detailVC, which is presenting addVC for the modification. Is it maybe the problem somehow?

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Comment: Interesting article. I think understand the concept. However classes are reference type, so if you make one equal each other, they will be referenced. The point I didn't know, that by telling the view controller classes  that "you two are on the same navigation stack" is already enough to make this happen. Correct me please, if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution!
As @Roberto and @matt pointed out, I created a new instance of the delegate VC, so the delegation was basically not working! I was confused, because all the print statements were working in the delegate function. That is not quite enough though.
 I also have put `addVC.delegate = self` in a wrong method! The Idea of changing this to `self.delgate = detailVC` in addVC class, is also wrong. 
The correct answer seems to be that in detailVC, when I am moving to AddVC, i do it like this:

```
 @objc func handleEdit() {
         let avc = AddVC()
        avc.lesson = self.lesson
        avc.delegate = self
         let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: avc)
         present(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
```

This way, by the time AddVC is presented, detailVC *already* knows, that she is the delegate! Why? Because this way I am telling detailVC, that the addVC I am referring to, is the rootController of the navigationController making the "segue". Because classes are reference type, this way the new instance of addVC will be identical, and referenced to the original. I hope I am understanding this correct.
But Working!

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new instance of `DetailTableViewController()` and assigning it to the delegate object. You're not invoking the DetailTableViewController that exists in your view hierarchy, but instead a new one.

You need to assign the delegate with your already existing view controller.

---

**Clarification:**

You're showing a `DetailTableViewController` in the screen. That's the view you want to update when you call the delegate. Let's call this `View A`.

When you assign the delegate, you're instantiating a new `DetailTableViewController`, which is **not** the `View A`, but instead a new object that you're not showing to the user. Let's call this `View B`.

When you execute the function `passLesson()`, you're calling the method `didAddLesson()` in the `View B`, which is not being showed to the user.

You shouldn't create the new `View B`, you need to use the `View A` in your delegate. How? Well, you somehow need to give the `View A` to your `AddVC` class and use it for your delegate.

TLDR: The line `let vc = DetailTableViewController()` is wrong. Don't instantiate a new controller, use your existing one.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how I do that? And as I said my function is being called (print statements are printing correct data) on my existing DetailViewController(), it is the UI which is not updating. Bit I might get something wrong here.

Comment: I don't know how to explain this by just writing, but I edited my answer to try to. I hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, so I created a shared instance of DetailTableViewController in DTVC, and in addVC ViewíDidLoad:       self.delegate = DetailTableViewController.shared, still no UI update, and still my function is being called, and printing data normally.

Comment: BTW when i did addVC.delegate = self in DetailViewController, the delegate function was not called.

Comment: I uploaded a demo project to GitHub to reproduce the issue, I hope it helps to see, what is happening [link] https://github.com/gerkov77/DataPassing/tree/master

Comment: what you explained here is right of course!. The thing I didn't get, how I am gonna make one VC know, that it is reverencing the "A", and not a completely new instance of the class, "B". Turned out for me, that telling the VC's that they are on the same navigation stack, does the job. I had to make further reading, and watching to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling your delegate from background thread?
If so, you need to wrap any UI update calls to be dispatched on the main queue, like this:

```swift
func didAddLesson(lesson: Lesson) { // my addVC is calling this through delegate
    self.lesson = lesson
    print("delegate function set navitem title: \(lesson.name!)")//printed out correctly

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.navigationItem.title = lesson.name! //nothing changes
        self.tableView.reloadData()// no reload
    }
}
```

Comment: I uploaded a demo project to GitHub to reproduce the issue, I hope it helps to see, what is happening [link] github.com/gerkov77/DataPassing/tree/master